# nganimate leave taking too long

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-animate

I'm using angular-ui-modal, which automatically applies nganimate classes when opening and closing a modal. This is causing all sorts of problems, not least the fact that the backdrop takes a while to be removed from the dom after my custom css transition has finished. It's hard to reproduce but basically I have the following SASS:

```
.modal-backdrop{

    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 4s ease-out;

    &.in{
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

}
```

When the in class is added, the backdrop fades in, but when the modal is closed the backdrop fades but stays in the dom with the "in-remove in-remove-active" classes for a while then the "ng-leave ng-leave-active" classes applied until it's removed.

I can't seem to work out how it calculates how long to wait before removing from the dom but it seems related to the transition time, putting it up to 4 seconds seemed to make it wait around 6 seconds in the in-remove stage and 6 seconds in the ng-leave stage. Reducing the transition time to 1 second made it wait about 2 seconds in each stage.

The ng-animate stuff seems completely removed from the ui-modal stuff. Like a black box you can't get into. ui-modal doesn't seem to have any settings to change the time that animations take so I can only assume it's incorrectly calculating it by looking at my css.

Comment: I have the same issue; have you found a solution?

Comment: Pretty much, will post a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two workarounds.

1) use pointer-events none to stop the blocking of the ui, as discussed here -https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5407

2) Use the JavaScript animation hooks. This wasn't working until a recent update but they say it is now fixed. Code would look like this...

```
angular.module('app').animation('.modal', [function() {

return {

    enter: function(element, doneFn) {

        console.log("entering");

        $(element).css({
            'opacity': '0', 
            'background-color': 'black'
        }).animate({
            opacity: 0.6
        }, 200, doneFn);

    },

    leave: function(element, doneFn) {

        console.log("leaving");

        $(element).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 200, doneFn);

    }
}

}]);
```

Sorry for the formatting, looks like you can't format code easily  on mobile version of Stack Overflow.